# `\AbbreviateFirstname` in librarian makes compilation hang

Tags: bibliographies, compilation-error

The `librarian` package parses bibfiles without running bibtex or biber.
However, in case one sets `\AbbreviateFirstname` and a name in the bibfile consists of one word only, the compilation hangs.

Minimal (non) working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{librarian}
\AbbreviateFirstname

\begin{filecontents}{bar.bib}
@article{foo1,
 author ={Anton Nonym},
 title  ={A title},
 journal={Top Journal},
 number ={42},
 year   ={2000}
}
@article{foo2,
 author ={Batman},
 title  ={Yet Another Title},
 journal={Flop Journal},
 number ={23},
 year   ={1999}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

A paper by
\Cite{foo1}{foo}{\ReadName{\Firstname\ \Lastname}}{??} % works always
and
\Cite{foo2}{foo}{\ReadName{\Firstname\ \Lastname}}{??}.% hangs for \AbbreviateFirstname

\BibFile{bar.bib}
\end{document}
```

If I comment out `\AbbreviateFirstname` or the second `\Cite`, the MWE works. *With* the second cite *and* `\AbbreviateFirstname`, the compilation<sup>1</sup> doesn't end (in the second run). Only after an abort by hand, I get the message:

```
! Interruption.
\lb@temp ->\lb@eoe 
                   \spacefactor 1000.
l.28 ...{foo}{\ReadName{\Firstname \Lastname}}{??}
```

What can I do to get a correct compilation (e.g. with an empty `\Firstname`) or at least an error message, without changing the bibfile?

<sup>1</sup> Executed with TeX Live 2022, latex, pdflatex, or lualatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that perhaps

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{librarian,etoolbox}
\AbbreviateFirstname
\makeatletter
\def\lb@@loopovernames#1#2#3#4{%
  \iflb@abbreviate
    \def\Firstname{}%
    \ifblank{#1}{}{\lb@abbreviate#1 lb@end }% add test for emptyness
  \else
    \def\Firstname{#1}%
  \fi
  \def\Von{#2}\def\Lastname{#3}\def\Junior{#4}%
  \lb@makerefname
  }
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents}{bar.bib}
@article{foo1,
 author ={Anton Nonym},
 title  ={A title},
 journal={Top Journal},
 number ={42},
 year   ={2000}
}
@article{foo2,
 author ={Batman},
 title  ={Yet Another Title},
 journal={Flop Journal},
 number ={23},
 year   ={1999}
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

A paper by
\Cite{foo1}{foo}{\ReadName{\Firstname\ \Lastname}}{??} % works always
and
\Cite{foo2}{foo}{\ReadName{\ifdefempty\Firstname{}{\Firstname\ }\Lastname}}{??}.% hangs for \AbbreviateFirstname

\BibFile{bar.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]